# Bounds on Wasserstein (Kantorovich) distance

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a Polish space endowed with a bounded metric $\rho_X$. Let $\mu, \mu'$ be two probability measures, and $\kappa, \kappa'$ be two stochastic kernels on $X$. Assume that $\kappa, \kappa'$ are Lipschitz in the following sense:
$$
  \bar\rho_X(\kappa(x), \kappa'(x')) \leq \gamma\cdot \rho_X(x, x')
$$
for some $\gamma > 0$ and all $x,x'\in X$. Here
$$
\bar\rho_X:(\nu,\nu')\to\inf_{N \in \mathcal C(\nu, \nu')}\int_{X^2} \rho_X(x, x')N(\mathrm dx\times \mathrm dx')
$$
is the Wasserstein distance on measures induced by the original metric $\rho_X$ on points. By $\mathcal C(\nu, \nu')$ I denote the set of all coupling of probability measures $\nu, \nu'$.

Consider now the product measures $P = \mu\otimes\kappa$ and $P' = \mu'\otimes \kappa'$, and let their right marginal be $\nu = \mu\kappa$ and $\nu' = \mu'\kappa'$. I think I can show that $\bar\rho_X(\nu, \nu') \leq \gamma \bar\rho_X(\mu, \mu')$ (if there is a textbook proof of this, I'd be interested in seeing it). Thus, if we assume the product metric to be 
$$
  \rho_{X^2}(x, x', y, y') = \rho_X(x,x') + \rho_X(y,y') \tag{1}
$$
we get
$$
  \bar\rho_{X^2}(P, P') \leq (1 + \gamma)\cdot \bar\rho_X(\mu, \mu').
$$
The same bounds would of course apply to the case
$$
  \rho_{X^2}(x, x', y, y') = \max(\rho_X(x,x'), \rho_X(y,y')), \tag{2}
$$
however I think that they are too conservative in this case. Is there a way to come with better bounds on the Wasserstein distance for the produce measure in case (2)?

---

Notation-wise: $P = \mu\otimes\kappa$ is the product measure, a unique solution for 
$$
  P(A\times B) = \int_A \kappa(B|x)\mu(\mathrm dx).
$$
Its marginals are $\mu$ and $\nu = \mu\kappa$, the latter define by 
$$
  \mu\kappa(B) = \int_X \kappa(B|x)\mu(\mathrm dx).
$$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the notation.  Is $P$ a single probability measure, or a family of probability measures, one for each $x \in X$?  How exactly is it defined?  I'm not clear as to what the $\otimes$ symbol means in this context.  Does $\nu = \mu \kappa$ denote the measure $\nu(A) = \int_X \kappa(x,A) \mu(dx)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: added. True for the $\nu$, and $P$ is the joint distribution with the left marginal $\mu$ and conditional probability $P$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: a typo, $\lambda = \gamma$